# Get Actual Error Message From Oracle Exception In Dot Net

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have this procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE MyProc
(
     <some-parameters>
)
AS
  BEGIN
    if(<some-condition>) then
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR('my custom error message');
    end if;
  END;
```

When calling it from C#:

```
try
{
    <call procedure>
}
catch(OracleException x)
{
    lblMessage.Text = x.Message;
}
```

I am getting error message like:

```
ORA-28008: my custom error message ORA-06512: at blah, line blah ORA-06512: at line blah
```

I want only:

```
my custom error message
```

There is no innerException. Errors collection don't help. Same situation when use Exception instead of OracleException.

What am I missing?

I can use string manipulation but how fixed is format of error message?

Comment: is the ORA-xxxxx number for the custom error message unique for every error message?

Answer (score 0):

I use return parameters to capture with php. I recon the same technique will be useful in .net. 
(I assume it's possible to catch the custom message in the exception handling and re-raising only that custom message, but underneath method works for sure. :)

```
create or replace PROCEDURE MyProc (p_result out varchar2)
is
  ...
begin
  ...
  if error then
    p_result := 'my custom error message';
    return; -- exit procedure 
  end if;

  p_result := 'ok';
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

PKG_MSG.RAISE_ERROR( 0,null,'my custom error message',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null );

instead of

RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR('my custom error message');

Comment: what is `pkg_msg`? Looks like a custom library/package.